# Interpolate/extrapolate from a unknown number of data points

Tags: functions

I am trying to build a computer program that will create a graph from a set of 20 numbers (20 years). The user can enter values for any of the 20 numbers (minimum of 2?) and the program will interpolate/extrapolate the rest to create the graph. Can anyone point me in the right direction for what kind of math this would take?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. You could use smoothing splines for this task. There is an R packagae that does that for you.

Comment: Btw any relation to Carl de  Boor? He was one of the founders of spline interpolation.

Comment: @Hans Engler Thanks, I'll look into it. And sorry, no relation that I'm aware of...